# module not found, j2me polish blackberry project

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-simulator, j2mepolish

I am using J2ME polish to build a project for blackberry packaging the project, I try to run it on a blackberry simulator, but the following error message appears:

Error `starting myapp: module myapp-10 not found`

how can i solve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you have not included the J2ME polish classes in the cod. Make sure you have checked the "order and export" checkbox for the jar in the project build path.

Comment: I'm using netbeans IDE and I'm pretty sure I configured J2ME polish in my build.xml, my app runs fine in OS 6 or greater, but gets the error on below OS versions.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, clearly you should use JDE corresponding to your OS version, so in order to build your app for all OS versions, you must download all the JDE's